# How to use lists from a text file in python?

Tags: python, list, file, python-3.x

i have been trying to read/write values(lists) in a .txt file and using them later, but i can't find a function or something to help me use these values as lists and not strings, since using the `readline` function doesn't help.

Also, im don't want to use multiple text files to make up 1 list

example:

```
v=[]
f = open("test.txt","r+",-1)
f.seek(0)
v.append(f.readline())
print(v)
```

in test.txt

```
cat, dog, dinosaur, elephant
cheese, hotdog, pizza, sushi
101, 23, 58, 23
```

im expecting to the list `v = [cat, dog, dinosaur, elephant]` in separate indexes, but by doing this code (which is totally wrong) i get this instead
`v = ['cat,dog,dinosaur,elephant']` which is what i don't want

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of what it is you are exactly trying to solve. Show a sample input you are sending to your code, and what the expected output should be. Show what is currently happening that should not be happening.

Comment: added example code for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading rows from a CSV file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428318/reading-rows-from-a-csv-file-in-python)

Comment: I had no idea about CSV when i made this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to read it as comma separated values.

Try the following

```
import csv
with open('test.txt', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

I believe that will put you on the right track. For more information about how the csv parser works, have a look at the docs

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: hey this works, altough, would this csv apply for another separation method? like `:` `;` ?

Comment: sure, just pop in the delimiter you want in the reader function, for example csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=':') to use : as a seperator

Comment: after further testing and reading, i'm interested in how do i select 1 single row? or shouls i transform the `print(row)` into `v.append(row)` and thus select the desired list using `v[0]`

Answer (score 1):

To me, it looks like you're trying to read a file, and split it by `,`.
This can be accomplished by

```
f = open("test.txt", "r+").read()
v = f.split(",")
print(v)
```

It should output

> ['cat', ' dog', ' dinosaur', ' elephant\ncheese', ...]

And so forth.

Comment: Tested this, it kinda works, but for some values it prints the `"`

Comment: @Aozyk And by `"` you mean...?

Comment: character `"`, it looks like this `['cat,dog,dinosaur,elephant ...]`

Comment: It would only do that if you had the `'` character inside your file. Do you?

Comment: i just had something else typed, sorry :p, but it wasn't on the file.

Comment: It's fine! Happy coding!