# Not able to open CSV file

Tags: python, csv, file

I am pretty new to python (or programming in general). Currently i am trying to open a CSV file.

```
with open("C:/Users/Sascha/Desktop/Kursmaterialien/Kursmaterialien/data/names.csv", "r") as file: 
    for line in file:
        print(line)
        break
```

For some reason python does not give me any responds (Not even a Traceback). That happend to me  earlier with another file aswell and i dont now what the problem is.... Sooo, what should i do?

Comment: It doesn't work like that, your code does the same as opening a csv file in notepad, which is nothing but bunch of junk you wont understand, you need some special libraries to read csv files in python you can use the csv or pandas library , you can learn how to do so here https://realpython.com/python-csv/.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading rows from a CSV file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428318/reading-rows-from-a-csv-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems that could raise the problem mentioned.

The first is that you have the wrong iterator. For reading lines `file.readlines()` is the appropriate function. To read the csv file as csv you can take advantage of [python's csv lib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

If you try to just read the first line use `file.readline()`. in your above mentioned code you use `break` after the first line. `break` ends the loop and in your case in the first iteration.

More informations on csvs with python [guru99](https://www.guru99.com/python-csv.html#:%7E:text=To%20read%20data%20from%20CSV,more%20intricate%20than%20it%20is.)

More information about working with files in python [realpython.com](https://realpython.com/working-with-files-in-python/)

For more help providing a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

are you importing csv?

```
import csv 
with open("file.csv", "r") as file: 
for line in file:
    print(line)
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

## How to load csv dataset and print

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/admin/Music/Project/AMia-1981-2021.csv')
print(data)
```