# Python read CSV file line by line in loop

Tags: python, csv

```
def read_file():
    with open("bla.csv", "r") as Blabla:
        reader = csv.reader(BlaBla)

        for column in reader:
            one = column[1]
            two = column[2]
            three = column[3]
            four = column[4]

            bla_line.append([one, two, three, four])

count, c = 50, 1
while c < count:
    read_file()

    c = c + 1
```

How is it possible to read the file line by line while looping? One line for every `c`.

```
c = 0 = read line 0
c = 1 = read line 1
c = 2 = read line 2
```

and so on and so on...

`islice`, `pandas`, and so on, didn't work it out for me so far.

I need this construction exact as it is for another function and later operations which are not listed here.

The `append` operations works fine so far. The issue here is to iterate over the file like I described.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading rows from a CSV file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428318/reading-rows-from-a-csv-file-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

This solution is reading the csv file line by line and returns a list of lists represents the raw csv file.

- bonus - you can ignore the csv headers if you need to :)

```py
def read_csv(path: str, ignore_headers: bool = False):
    with open(path, 'r') as csv:
        res = []
        for line_number, line in enumerate(csv.readlines()):
            if ignore_headers and line_number == 0:
                continue
            else:
                res.append(line.strip().split(','))

    return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    csv_content = '''first_name,last_name,age
    John,Harris,23
    Omar,Ahmed,19'''
    with open('temp.csv', 'w') as _file:
        for line in csv_content:
            _file.write(line)
    csv = read_csv('temp.csv')
    print(csv)
    csv = read_csv('temp.csv', ignore_headers=True)
    print(csv)
```

Hoped it helps!

Answer (score 0):

hope this will read the `csv` file line by line

```
with open("bla.csv") as f:
    lis = [line.split() for line in f]        # create a list of lists
    for i, x in enumerate(lis):              #print the list items 
        print "line{0} = {1}".format(i, x))
```