# Open last saved CSV file via python

Tags: python, csv

I have a file to be downloaded in CSV format every day that it's name changes daily. how can i open that file via python in Excel after being downloaded automatically?

I've tried the below solution but i have to mention the file name in full which I can't do because it changes dynamically.

```
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen('filename.csv', shell=True)
```

Comment: is the date in the filename?

Comment: `Popen` is used to run a shell command. You probably meant to use `open`. More to the point, though: you could get the list of CSVs in the download folder, sort them by creation date, and open the newest one.

Comment: Or you could generate the file name and open it directly (assuming it’s predictable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your code that downloads the file You can find latest file in your download folder as and open it

```
import glob
import os
from subprocess import Popen

list_of_files = glob.glob('/path_to_download_folder/*.csv') 
latest_csv_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print(latest_csv_file)
#then do what ever you want to do with it.
os.startfile(latest_csv_file)
```

Comment: Perfection ! it catches the name correctly. now how to open it ?

Comment: depends what do you want to do with it . to read it as csv https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428318/reading-rows-from-a-csv-file-in-python

Comment: i want to open it in excel application not python

Comment: import os 
os.startfile(file_name)